# Serviço para redimensionar imagens enviadas para um site WordPress

Tags: html, wordpress, imagem, edição-de-imagens

Tenho um site WordPress o qual tenho maior dor de cabeça para redimensionar imagens, e acho que um script PHP que redimensiona imagens não é a solução para mim.

Toda publicação envolve cerca de 3 imagens, é muito cansativo criar vários redimensionamentos; existe algum site na web que permite que eu envie as fotos e escolha o tamanho da largura, ex: `width: 250px`?

Quando eu envio uma imagem para colocar como destaque ela fica com a resolução original, se for uma imagem 4.000px x 2.000px ela vai ficar muito pesada. Não preciso de uma imagem desse tamanho, o que eu quero é só reduzir a resolução da imagem (pixels), fazendo assim, as imagens ficando leves.

Ou existe algum plugin para WordPress que me ajude em algo?

Comment: Por mais que você tenha dito que um script em PHP não é uma solução, fiquei curioso em saber o motivo. No seu caso, se a aplicação estiver rodando em um servidor Linux, você poderia resolver facilmente com ImageMagick, veja: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/mogrify.php É possível, inclusive, redimensionar imagens em lote, ao invés de uma por uma.

Comment: É que eu preciso ter o arquivo (.png/.jpg/.gif), para fazer upload, e não um script php, o que preciso é da imagem (arquivo) redimensionada.

Comment: Desculpe-me, mas ainda não entendi o seu problema. O site é seu ou você é um usuário deste site? Não creio que os links abaixo vão te ajudar, pois você só pode redimensionar uma imagem por vez. Para três imagens, serão necessárias três utilizações distintas em ambas as opções listadas na resposta abaixo.

Comment: A observação do @cantoni é a definição do [Problema XY](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/499/201)...

Comment: Eu uso o Wordpress. Eu sou sim o dono do site, só que quando eu envio uma imagem para colocar como destaque ela fica com a resolução original, se for uma imagem 4.000px x 2.000px ela vai ficar muito pesada, não é necessário uma imagem desse tamanho, o que eu quero é só reduzir a resolução da imagem (pixels), fazendo assim, as imagens ficando leves. Ou você conhece algum plugin para wordpress que me ajude em algo?

Comment: @AlexandreLopes, de acordo com seu comentário acima, criei uma resposta, pois achei mais apropriado para o contexto da sua pergunta.

Comment: Recomendo que o @AlexandreLopes também leia sobre o [Problema XY](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/499/201), visto que tem sido comum este tipo de pergunta no SOpt.

Answer (score 4):

De acordo com os comentários descritos na pergunta, entendi o problema e creio que uma solução interessante é utilizar o ImageMagick, por causa disso criei essa resposta.

Existe port do ImageMagick para o Windows e pode ser baixado aqui:

[ImageMagick para Windows](https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows)

Alguma das vantagens do ImageMagick sobre qualquer serviço Web, são:

1. É executado localmente. Não há risco das imagens em questão pararem em indexadores de busca. Lembre-se que esses serviços web recebem a sua imagem, fazem o processamento (provavelmente com o ImageMagick ou similar) e devolvem uma imagem processada. Não há garantias que as imagens lá armazenadas não podem um dia parar em indexadores de busca como o Google, etc. Esse mesmo princípio vale para os famosos conversores de PDF para DOC, etc; Portanto, se o arquivo a ser convertido é confidencial, nunca utilize qualquer serviço web.
2. O processamento local tende a ser mais rápido, já que esses serviços, por serem gratuitos, geralmente não rodam em servidores poderosos;
3. Você pode realizar o processamento em um lote de imagens (por exemplo, uma pasta com vários JPGs). Muito útil quando você quer enviar suas imagens para o Picasa, por exemplo. Você reduz para 1600x1200, o que deixa o upload mais rápido;

O programa deve ser utilizado por linha de comando, veja alguns exemplos abaixo:

```
mogrify -resize 1600x1200 *.jpg
```

O exemplo acima redimensiona todos os arquivos da pasta atual para a resolução de 1600x1200. Note que os arquivos após processados terão o mesmo nome do original (os arquivos serão perdidos). Portanto, garanta que o comando não será executado nos arquivos originais.

```
mogrify -path imgs/ -resize 800x600 *.jpg
```

Já o comando acima, reduzirá os arquivos da pasta atual para a resolução de 800x600, entretanto, os arquivos processados serão salvos na pasta imgs (que, no caso acima, deve estar dentro da pasta atual). Assim, não há risco dos arquivos originais serem modificados.

Existe várias outras opções na linha de comando e essa é uma das grandes vantagens do ImageMagick.

[Alguns exemplos de uso do ImageMagick](http://muhdzamri.blogspot.com.br/2010/06/batch-resize-your-images-using-mogrify.html)
[Mais Exemplos](http://dptnt.com/2007/09/batch-resize-images-using-imagemagick/)

Comment: Cantoni Você poderia dar uma olhada nessa outra pergunta?
http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/20662/como-instalar-imagemagick-no-windows-7-32-bits
 Agradeço!

Comment: @AlexandreLopes, você teve algum problema para utilizar o ImageMagick?

Comment: Nenhum! Redondinho!! perfeito.

Answer (score 3):

Duas boas ferramentas online que fazem isso é o [Quick Thumbnail](http://quickthumbnail.com/) e [ResizeImageOnline](http://www.resizeyourimage.com/).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Um plugin é [bem fácil](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/54059/12615):

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: (SOPT) Substituir Imagens Originais
 * Description: Substitui imagens originais (full size) pelo tamanho "grande" na hora do upload. 
   Ajuda a economizar espaço em disco, já que uma foto de 3240x4320 (5MB) pode se converter
   em uma de 768x1024 (108KB - exemplo depende do ajuste em /wp-admin/options-media.php e da qualidade jpeg). 
 * Author: brasofilo
 * Plugin URI: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/54059/12615
 */

add_filter( 'wp_generate_attachment_metadata','replace_uploaded_image_wpse_48882' );
add_filter( 'jpeg_quality', 'qualidade_jpeg_sopt_19538' );

/**
 * Replace original by largest size on upload
 * 
 * @author brasofilo
 * @wp_hook wp_generate_attachment_metadata
 * 
 * @param object Image information
 * @return object
 */
function replace_uploaded_image_wpse_48882( $image_data ) 
{
    // if there is no large image : return
    if ( !isset( $image_data['sizes']['large'] ) ) 
        return $image_data;

    // paths to the uploaded image and the large image
    $upload_dir              = wp_upload_dir();
    $uploaded_image_location = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/' . $image_data['file'];
    $large_image_location    = $upload_dir['path'] . '/' . $image_data['sizes']['large']['file'];

    // delete the uploaded image
    unlink( $uploaded_image_location );

    // rename the large image
    rename( $large_image_location, $uploaded_image_location );

    // update image metadata and return them
    $image_data['width']  = $image_data['sizes']['large']['width'];
    $image_data['height'] = $image_data['sizes']['large']['height'];
    unset($image_data['sizes']['large']);

    return $image_data;
}

/**
 * Qualidade: de 0 a 100
 */
function qualidade_jpeg_sopt_19538() 
{
    return 75;
}
```

Também é possível setar a qualidade do JPEG de maneira [avançada](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/138775/12615) e usar um tamanho customizado:

```
add_image_size( 'new-large', 1600, 1200 ); /* definido em functions.php ou num plugin */
```

- trocando todas as ocorrências de `$image_data['sizes']['large']` por `$image_data['sizes']['new-large']`.

Comment: Olá @brasofilo, muito obrigado pela contribuição, porém, como eu mencionei acima, eu preciso da imagem redimensionada para fazer upload, então essa não é a solução.
Mais com certeza sua grande resposta vai ajudar várias outras pessoas. No momento eu ainda estou usando o programa ImageResizer.
Mas brasofilo, você poderia detalhar melhor o plugin? Como funciona, etc... Parece ser excelente! :D

Comment: Claro, porque fazer localmente é a solução. Fazer upload pra redimensionar, fazer download e depois subir de volta pro site não parece legal... Você acha que a descrição do plugin dentro do código insuficiente? Talvez não seja óbvio de primeira e melhor colocar no texto da resposta?

Comment: Sim, bras! :D :§