# Como instalar ImageMagick no windows 7 [ 32 bits ]?

Tags: imagemagick

Como faço para instalar e configurar o `ImageMagick` no **windows 7**  [ *32 bits* ], e como faço para colocar os comandos nele?

No meu caso, preciso colocar o comando:

```
$ mkdir -p resultado

$ mogrify -path resultado -resize 50% *.jpg
```

Comment: Olá @AlexandreLopes, nunca instalei no Windows. Vou fazer isso agora e te dou um retorno assim que terminar.

Comment: Obrigadooooo!!!

Comment: Adicionei a resposta. Funcionou perfeitamente. Não foi necessário nenhuma configuração extra. Foi instalar e rodar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para Windows 7, 32 Bits, utilize a seguinte instalação:

[ImageMagick para Windows 32 Bits](https://ftp.icm.edu.pl/packages/ImageMagick/binaries/ImageMagick-6.8.9-3-Q16-x86-dll.exe)

Instale normalmente, com as opções padrão.

Após instalar, vá para o console do Windows (cmd).

Digite o seguinte comando e veja se você tem o mesmo retorno da imagem abaixo.

```
convert -version
```

[image: Retorno do convert -version]

Se funcionar o comando acima, então siga os seguintes passos:

**Passo1**: Crie uma pasta e coloque os arquivos a serem redimensionados dentro dela. Note que no meu caso são vários arquivos BMP.

[image: Crie uma pasta e coloque os arquivos a serem redimensionados dentro dela]

**Passo2**: Crie uma pasta dentro da pasta atual. Essa pasta receberá os arquivos redimensionados. Eu dei o nome de small, conforme imagem abaixo.

[image: Criando pasta que receberá os arquivos]

**Passo3**: Rode o comando **mogrify -path small -resize 50% *.bmp**

Note na imagem abaixo o tamanho dos arquivos antes da conversão. Repare também a a linha de comando acima.

[image: Executando o comando mogrify]

**Passo4**: Confirmação do resultado. Entre na pasta small, execute um **dir** e veja como o tamanho dos arquivos foi alterado.

[image: Conferindo o resultado]

Comment: Muuuuuuuuuitoooo Obrigadooooooo!!!!!!

Comment: Qualquer problema estamos aí.

Comment: Ok, caso eu tenha alguma dúvida eu retorno aqui! :D